# Xcode: stop lines of code / functions from compiling

Tags: swift, xcode, preprocessor

I have common files in several projects and I need to stop from compiling some lines and functions for project A, meanwhile it should be compiled for project B.

I know that I can use preprocessor. But it's not convenient for me. Is there any way to stop lines of code from compiling with condition like below?

```
#if PhotosModuleSettings.type == .documents
... do not commpile
#endif
```

Comment: You need to explain in what way the preprocessor in not convenient. More importantly, you need to explain what you imagine `PhotosModuleSettings.type == .documents` means. What are any of those identifiers? Are they classes, properties, and enum members? Are they references to Xcode build settings? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's not convenient about using the preprocessor?  You can specify the preprocessor macros in build settings of each target, or you can use .xcconfig files to specify them.

There's another simple way to do it, however.  Separate the lines and functions that you want to conditionally compile into separate files. Maybe by using Swift extensions or subclassing or just separate global functions, etc..whatever.  Then just choose which target(s) and/or project(s) you want those files added as membership.

Depending on your desire to refactor your code to make such a file separation, the preprocessor macros may be the better way to go, though.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make use of pre processor macros.

Add a configuration for your project, and use that in the pre processor macros.

You can set the value for these configuration in the pre processor macros section for your targets based on your build configuration.

Here is a detailed [blog](https://innovaptor.com/blog/2013/09/02/xcode-preprocessor-macros-for-test-code/) related to the same concept