# SwiftUI: How to work with non-simulator supported frameworks and PreviewProvider?

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I'm working on a RealityKit app, and using SwiftUI.

Of course RealityKit view's does not work in the SwiftUI `PreviewProvider` preview. But my issue is that even simple and completely isolated SwiftUI views won't preview, since the `PreviewProvider` needs to compile the entire project.

My SwiftUI View classes aren't connected to ARView code in any way. It's enough if I just go "File" -> "New" and choose a SwiftUI file, and then try to preview that in the canvas (⌥ + ⌘ + ↵), without any changes. Then it will give me that error. Just the fact that there is any code in my `.xcodeproj` that is not supportet by the canvas preview, gives an error.

I get errors like this:

```
Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'installGestures'
```

My only two solutions for now is to 1) copy file to a Playground and experiment with it there, then copy back when finished. 2) comment out all unsupported RealityKit related code, before working on the view.

#### Q: Of course non of those solutions are optimal. Any better solutions out there?

Comment: Search here on *[xcode] swift conditional build*. I received 26 hits, including this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133043/xcode-stop-lines-of-code-functions-from-compiling/55133440#55133440 Now if those results won't help, removing "swift" expands the results to 188. Your answer really is to use Xcode for a conditional build. But the easiest way? Use a device that is running iOS 13. I know, that may not be feasible, but you'll at least get a feel for real-time performance and other issues you nay not have thought of.

Comment: Does this also happen in Beta6? I read somewhere that it is supposed to be a bug.

Comment: @Fabian Yes, it happens on the latest beta as well. Do you remember where you read that? Twitter or a blog?

Comment: Sadly not anymore, I hope they fix it if possible

Comment: Let's hope so. It seems like a bug, since it seems reasonable to be able to preview a nisolated SwiftUI view file, without it being dependent on all other unrelated files in my `.xcodeproj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. My solution was to use the targetEnvironment(simulator) compiler directive like so:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    var body: some View {
            #if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
            ARViewContainer()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .statusBar(hidden: true)
            #endif
        }
    }
}

#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        // ARKit / RealityKit specific code
        ...

        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
#endif
```

Further reading: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-compiler-directives-to-detect-the-ios-simulator

Answer (score 1):

While the new simulator in iOS 13 supports Metal, ARView requires an actual device to capture camera frames and generate sensor fusion data. And it has a ton of properties and methods that you would need to mock to allow interaction with other code.

Can you abstract ARView interaction between SwiftUI through a protocol implemented by another class, such as a UIView or UIViewController subclass? If the protocol is simple enough, you can create a class that can mock the interaction - responding to your SwiftUI views as if it was actually communicating with ARView, without implementing the entire ARView API.

Your SwiftUI views probably shouldn't be dealing with setup and arbitrary access to ARView's properties and methods directly. You can create a wrapper around an ARView and present application level logic and actions though Combine publishers and subscribers. A mock version of that wraps a UIView and has the same pub/subs can present simple visual cues, like change colors, to represent different states of the ARView, etc.

Comment: My SwiftUI View classes aren't connected to ARView code in any way. It's enough if I just go "File" -> "New" and choose a SwiftUI file, and then try to preview that in the canvas (⌥ + ⌘ + ↵), without any changes. Then it will give me that error. Just the fact that there is any code in my `.xcodeproj` that is not supportet by the canvas preview, gives an error.